# Show aspx web form in ASP.NET MVC Core Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, reportviewer

I know it was possible in ASP.NET MVC web applications to embed a web form (.aspx file which inherited from `System.Web.UI.Page`) into a razor page using an `<iframe>` tag.

```
<iframe src="/MyWebForm.aspx" .../>
```

Now, I am developing an ASP.NET Core MVC web application (targeting the full .NET Framework 4.5.2) and I can't seem to figure out how to get this working. Specifically, I'm trying to embed an SSRS report viewer into a web form, and then show that web form within an `<iframe>` in my razor page.

I've seen numerous examples online of nuget packages that do exactly this and provide an HtmlHelper extension method to render the necessary `<iframe>`. A good example is [ReportViewerForMvc](https://reportviewerformvc.codeplex.com/) which can be used like below.

```
// File: ReportViewer.cshtml

@using ReportViewerForMvc
@model Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer

<h2>Example Report</h2>
@Html.ReportViewer(Model) // This exension method does all the work of creating the iframe tag
```

I have looked at the source code for ReportViewerForMvc and re-designed the class library to use the AspNetCore libraries. The problem is my web application doesn't load the .aspx web form in the iframe (which is located in the wwwroot folder).

```
<iframe src="/MyWebForm.aspx" />
```

Is this even possible anymore? If anyone can provide just a simple working example, I think I could figure it out from there.

Comment: did you consider having 2 websites and embed your web form site using absolute url in your iframe ?

Comment: @aguafrommars, I have considered that. It kind of seems like overkill. I would have to share the authentication token between the two sites. But for a simple thing like showing a report, I was hoping there would be a better way.

Comment: @darrunategui got any solution ?.